# Avoid multiple instances of Singleton?

Tags: java, scala, design-patterns, singleton

I believe when a singleton object gets serialized and is then deserialized upon a plethora of times in series, there are multiple instances of singletons created.

How can you avoid such a situation?

Comment: What's the point of the "scala" tag here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, when you are creating a Singleton, you make sure that there is only one instance of it. you could do it that way:

```
public static class Singleton{
    private final static Singleton instance;

    private Singleton(){}

    public static Singleton getInstance(){
        if(instance == null)
            instance = new Singleton();
        return instance;
    }


}
```

Putting the constructor to `private` makes sure that no one except this class can create an instance of Singleton.

You only need to call the Singleton with getInstance and the Singleton do all the work on its side.

Comment: It's best to make the class final and the constructor private, so that no one can create a subclass which allows additional objects of type Singleton to be created.

Comment: @Arkanon Thanks! I made the changes.

Comment: Also, the Singleton `instance` should be static.

Comment: I don't think this answer addresses the serialize/de-serialize issue

Comment: @AmirAfghani I also think it doesn't.

Comment: This answer does NOT provide a secure possibility to really have only one instance of this class. See Amir Afghani answer.

Answer (score 4):

Joshua Bloch talks about using an enum as a singleton to avoid this specific issue in [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683).  Check out this article: [Why Enums are Better Singletons](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/07/why-enum-singleton-are-better-in-java.html) -or- read it directly from Bloch [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=3).

Comment: +1 from me. Very good reference/link.

Comment: Enums requires more memory, see this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hzs6OBcvNQE

Comment: That video is specific to Android, and it’s the difference between 2K and 4K bytes.........